# Abnormal server load on centos 6

Tags: centos

Last 3 nights at exactly 00:00 UTC the server stops responding, all services are also halted and the server load goes to 1800-3500, when we only have 24 processors. We were only able to login at start page of WHM, also could not connect via ssh. In WHM process manager we saw a lot of `ps -fe` processes taking a lot of load raning from 0% to 13400%. Also we got errors like `2019/02/06 01:00:10 [crit] 24232#0: accept4() failed (23: Too many open files in system); proftpd[3208]: 213.136.76.210 - error: unable to accept an incoming connection: Too many open files in system; kernel: [82478.961892] VFS: file-max limit 131072 reached; [Wed Feb 06 01:39:35 2019] [emerg] (23)Too many open files in system: Couldn't create pollset in child; check system or user limits`

Also yesterday after using lsof, a lot of lines like:

```
sshd      31611       root  mem       REG                8,2       124624  152567850 /lib64/libselinux.so.1
sshd      31611       root  mem       REG                8,2        22536  152568210 /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
sshd      31611       root  mem       REG                8,2        58480  152567836 /lib64/libpam.so.0.82.2
sshd      31611       root  mem       REG                8,2       144208  152568295 /lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0
sshd      31611       root  mem       REG                8,2        43256  152567966 /lib64/libwrap.so.0.7.6
sshd      31611       root  mem       REG                8,2        12688  152567978 /lib64/libfipscheck.so.1.1.0
sshd      31611       root  mem       REG                8,2       157072  152567862 /lib64/ld-2.12.so
```

Was not really able to find the cause of this problem. We are running WHM v76.0.18 on CENTOS 6.7

Comment: The starting point surely is to check what jobs get kicked off at 00:00 UTC. There are several `cron` files to consider, along with any `at` jobs that may have been queued.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reproduce the problem:

- Check if you have any `cron` jobs running at this time and find out what they are doing. Pay special attention to scripts that are not part of a software package but written by yourself or another user.
- Check the parent processes of the many `ps -fe` processes. Maybe you find a buggy script somewhere.

A running `sshd` process having opened several libraries is normal behavior, but many running processes may indicate a problem.

Comment: Problem is that during high load we cannot access console via ssh clients. Only whm main/process manager pages are working. 3 days ago we did not have any problem and also have not implemented anything new during this time. Anyway thanks.

Comment: It might also seems we are not being told the whole story in the question....Should not this a comment. As an answer it is very low quality.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm not sure. I think it is an answer in the sense how to proceed to find the cause of the problem, assuming "how to find the cause" is the question. It is not an answer to the question "what is the cause". The low quality of the answer is based on the available information.

Comment: @Masyaf If you cannot open a new SSH connection when the load is high, maybe you can start a SSH connection now and keep it open in case the problem occurs again. If necessary you could even run a script that prints something every few minutes.